# camera controls are broken when click on button/show modal on scene screen

Tags: flutter, 3d

In this Flutter code (I gave a simple example with a repetition of the bug), when i click on button, my camera controls of `ModelViewer` from `model_viewer_plus.dart` are broken:

```
main.dart
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:model_viewer_plus/model_viewer_plus.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ModelViewer Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isHavePhoto = true; // Example boolean value for visibility

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String mannequinLink = ''; // Example link for the bundled asset file

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ModelViewer Demo'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          ModelViewer(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF4D4D4D),
            src: 'https://modelviewer.dev/shared-assets/models/Astronaut.glb',
            alt: "3d",
            ar: false,
            cameraControls: true,
          ),
          Visibility(
            visible: isHavePhoto,
            child: Positioned(
              top: 64,
              right: 16,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 48,
                height: 48,
                child: IconButton(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  iconSize: 24,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.photo),
                  onPressed: () {
                    print('object');
                    // Perform the desired action
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is a known issue and it is open on github:
https://github.com/omchiii/model_viewer_plus.dart/issues/65

And if it could be helpfuly: on android this works correctly